# Sequelize v5.21 error while initializing model. Dependency name must be given as a not empty string

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I have managed to pinpoint the source of the error, despite it not mentioning any file name or anything. The error is `Unhandled rejection TypeError: Dependency name must be given as a not empty string`

It is occurring when I try to initialize the below model in my Express App

```
 'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Order = sequelize.define('Order', {

    customerName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },

    customerContact: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },

    address: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },

    additionalDetails: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },

    areaId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: sequelize.Area,
        key: 'id'
      }
    },

    createdBy: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: sequelize.User,
        key: 'id'
      }
    },

  }, {});
  Order.associate = function(models) {
    // Order.belongsTo(models.Area, {foreignKey: 'areaId', as: 'area'});
  };

  return Order;
};
```

However, if I comment/remove the `areaId` and `createdBy` attributes the app runs without error and the corresponding tables are created in MySQL Database.

Is there something I am doing wrong, I am using the same syntax in my other models to define foreign keys and they seem to run without error.

Any help would be appreciated, also if someone could point a way to get more descriptive errors while using Sequelize in Express it would be very helpful, as locating the source took me a lot of time due to numerous model definitions.

Comment: And what are the relationships among Customer, User, and Area models?

Comment: Your models User and Area should be registered in sequelize BEFORE Order model registration

Comment: @Anatoly I did try that, but I got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was resolved after I defined the associations that used `areaId` and `createdBy` as foreign keys. Don't know why but without the associations defined, the foreign keys would give an error. Now my model definition is as below

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Order = sequelize.define('Order', {

    customerName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },

    customerContact: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },

    address: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },

    additionalDetails: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },

    areaId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: sequelize.Area,
        key: 'id'
      }
    },

    createdBy: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: sequelize.User,
        key: 'id'
      }
    },

    status: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: 'pending'
    }

  }, {});
  Order.associate = function(models) {
    Order.belongsTo(models.Area, {foreignKey: 'areaId', as: 'area'});
    Order.belongsTo(models.User, {foreignKey: 'createdBy', as: 'user'});
  };

  return Order;
};
```